# Handling laravel api resource store and create endpoints

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5

I have the following in my controller

```
class WrittersController extends Controller
{

  public function index()
   {
      return view('backend.writters.dashboard');
   }

 public function store(Request $request){
  //confused on when to use this
 }

public function create(Request $request){
 //add new user functionality
```

}

Now in my routes i would like to use the resource routes

```
Route::resource('writters','WrittersController');
```

Now the confusion comes in my vue axios http endpoints. I uderstand that i index is a get request but axios doesnt have a store or create point.

When should i use the store and create endpoints in the vuejs

UPDATE ON MY AXIOS. Am using axios via

```
axios.post("url") //how do i go about create and store here
```

Comment: I don't understand "axios doesnt have a store or create point"  can you show us an example in your code how you are using axios? i.e. the `axios.get(...)` or `axios.post(...)`

Comment: am using axios.post("url")

Answer (score 2):

The store function is called when you want to create i.e you will create and then store. So I usually call the create method from inside the store. I do this just to seperate the code and make it more readable. There is no store or create http requests. The store uses post request. So you will need to use post request with axios. Just use Route::resource in your web.php and then go to the terminal and check your routes with

`php artisan routes (laravel 4)
php artisan route:list (laravel 5)`

This will list all your registered routes and tell you which functions they use.

Answer (score 1):

You use the other resources in the same way you used it for the get request.

Assuming your resource route looks like the following.

```
Route::resource('/mydata', 'MyDataController');
```

You would construct your requests in the following manner.

As you observed already, if you use  `axios.get('/mydata')`  you are routed to the `index` method.  However if you use `axios.post('/mydata')`, Laravel will automatically route you to the `store` method.

If you want to use the create action you change the url to use `axios.get('/mydata/create')` and you are routed to the `create` method. Please note that the `create` action is not used for creating the record but rather for fetching the view where the user will create the record, e.g. a form.  Then you will `store` the data entered in that form with a POST request.

If you want to use PUT (or PATCH) you use `axios.put(/mydata/{some_id})` and you are routed to the `update` method.

So Laravel handles all the routing automatically for you depending on the type of request that is made (GET, POST, PUT/PATCH, DELETE).  You only need to supply a parameter in the URL for those "Verbs" that require it.

Look at the documentation here [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers) Look for the chart or table labeled "Actions Handled By Resource Controller"   and you will see the various actions what verbs to access them with, and their respective URLs and Routes.

---

Also note that you can add custom methods to the resource controller if needed, but you will have to define the route.  You do this by declaring the route in your routes file e.g. `web.php` before you declare the actual resource.

Say you want to add an new post method 'archived' to mark some record as being no longer active. You would do something like the following in your routes.

```
Route::post('/mydata/archived/{some_id}', 'MyDataController@archive');
Route::resource('/mydata', 'MyDataController');
```

---

As demonstrated above you can use `axios.put()` or `axios.patch()` and they will both be routed to the `update` method.  There are times when you need to handle those requests differently.  For example when using a autosave feature and I want to validate some form data when only one field has changed, I would use patch to validate just that single field as follows.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    if($request->isMethod('patch')){
        $this->validateSingle($request);
    }else{
        $this->validateAll($request);
    }

    //....
}
```